# Export Datatable to CSV with special BackColour of a row

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, csv

I am exporting a `DataTable` to CSV with C#.
Along with the export, I would like to pass some formatting information, particularly changing the backcolor of a specific row.

Comment: Is that a DataTable object in C#, or a database table? What do you mean 'back color' - in an Excel document, for example? What have you tried already?

Comment: with csv format you cannot format the cell style, you would have to generate and excell document: Office Open XML (for Excel2007 and above), Excel 2003 XML (for Excel 2003 and above)

Answer (score 2):

A CSV doesn't have any formatting in it, it's just a set of values separated by commas.

If you mean to show a background colour in Excel, you may be better off writing HTML (with styling for the background colour) instead of plain text CSV, and giving it an XLS file extension so that Excel opens it.

Of course, doing that you'll lose the ability to easily parse the CSV in another application.

Answer (score 1):

As [pete the pagan-gerbil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92080/pete-the-pagan-gerbil) stated, this is not possible. A .csv (or **c**omma **s**eparated **v**alue)-file, really is just a .txt-file, containing *data* separated by *delimiters* (usually commas, semicolons or tab-spaces).

Imagine a .txt-file in windows notepad, there is no way to integrate any markup here, except for fancy characters (like adding ********--IMPORTANT-->******** to special line) or writing text in UPPERCASE, but this would of course just mess around with your actual *values* instead of marking up the *cells in the table*.

Markup is actually more of a job for *viewing* program that imports the .csv, e.g.: Excel.

As I see the thing, you have two options here:

- Export to .xls, then you would be able to use the formatting options provided by Excel.
- Export special "regex"-style characters to a field called "FormattingInformation" or so, and then process those informations in the displaying program (e.g.: Excel with VBA-Macro)